# How do I resolve this linker error in my C++ Windows app using shellscalingapi.h

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm trying to write a C++ application and get a linker error, I think I need to go in the project settings (Visual Studio) and add a lib file but I do not know what's the name and location of this file, how do I find out?

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "aviDrawDX.h"
#include "aviDrawDX.h"
#include "shellscalingapi.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <winuser.h>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE);

1>aviDrawDX.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SetProcessDpiAwareness referenced in function wWinMain
1>C:\Users\frank\Daten\Projekte\CPP\aviDrawDX\x64\Debug\aviDrawDX.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "aviDrawDX.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved, I needed to add shcore.lib in the Linker options.

Comment: Each API description in MSDN docs has a section describing the header and the lib file you must include.

Header shellscalingapi.h
Library Shcore.lib
DLL Shcore.dll